# What action can be taken if hostel allotments are not out just after admissions are done?

Tags: university, disciplinary-action

I just joined a university for my post graduation studies, but as I'm from a different country, I don't have a place to stay. Therefore, I asked the hostel prefect if I can stay in a room as a paying guest until the hostel allotment are out. He said yes. After two weeks however, the DEAN OF STUDENTS WELFARE asked me to leave the place the same day. He took our names and now I got a letter for disciplinary action. What should I do now?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking here, and I suspect it's off-topic on Academia S.E. since it's institution-specific. But to make a long story short, it sounds like you need to find new accommodations.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things you need to do:

1. Apologize to the Dean of Student Welfare for the unauthorized stay in the hostel, explaining that you thought you had permission.
2. Find somewhere to stay. Possible resources include hotels, AirBnB, the university's housing department, the Dean of Student Welfare (after or as part of step 1), and personal contacts in your department.